# Scintilla folding for custom lexer

Tags: c#, implementation, lexer, folding, scintilla

I am using the ScintillaNET wrapper for the Scintilla control and want to implement folding for ASM so I looked up http://sphere.sourceforge.net/flik/docs/scintilla-folding.html for reference on how to do it. Since I have never worked with C++ before, I am having a lot of problems trying to understand it. When it says register the margin click event, where and how do I register it? Also, when it says set some properties to the lexer, where exactly and how do I set them?

I tried asking at the scintilla interest group but I didn't get any help from there. If someone has set up folding for their own lexer in scintilla, help  on how do implement it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile there is a LexASM with folding included available:
http://groups.google.com/group/scintilla-interest/browse_thread/thread/aa56b57bc71e43ac
It's part of next version (2.25) of Scintilla/SciTE.
dlchnr